# Iterate a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a simple page that will show book information, I was going to store it all in a database but I have decided it would be better to just build a multidimensional array and store it in that.

There is just 4 "books" in the example below but there could be up to 100 eventually.

I need help iterating over this array and showing each item in an HTML `<li>` but I need to only show 4 in a row then start a new row.  Can someone show me how to accomplish this?

```
<?php
$books = array(
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'book 1 name here',
            'url' => '',
            'big_photo' => 'big photo of book 1',
            'small_photo' => 'small photo of book 1',
            'bio' => 'short bio 1'
            ),
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'book 2 name here',
            'url' => '',
            'big_photo' => 'big photo of book 2',
            'small_photo' => 'small photo of book 2',
            'bio' => 'short bio 2'
            ),
        3 => array(
            'name' => 'book 3 name here',
            'url' => '',
            'big_photo' => 'big photo of book  3',
            'small_photo' => 'small photo of book 3',
            'bio' => 'short bio 3'
            ),
        4 => array(
            'name' => 'book 4 name here',
            'url' => '',
            'big_photo' => 'big photo of book 4',
            'small_photo' => 'small photo of book 4',
            'bio' => 'short bio 4'
            )
);

echo $books["1"]["small_photo"];
?>
```

Example output

```
<ul>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li class="lastRow">books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li class="lastRow">books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li>books data</li>
    <li class="lastRow">books data</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample ... `HTML` format you are looking for so that we can be on same page

Comment: Somebody is spamming this Q and its answers with downvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$perRow=4;
$i = 0;
foreach($books as $book){
    if($i === 0){
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
        echo '<div>';
        echo $book['name']. '<br>';
        echo $book['url']. '<br>';
        echo $book['big_photo']. '<br>';
        echo $book['small_photo']. '<br>';
        echo $book['bio']. '<br><br><br>';
        echo '</div>';

    if($i === $perRow){
        $i = 0;
        echo '</div>';
    }else{
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've written any PHP but this should do it:

```
$numBooks = count($books);
$j = 0
for ($i = 0; $i < $numBooks; i+=4)
{
    for ($j = $i; $j < $i + 4; $j < $numBooks; ++$j)
    {
        if ($j == 3)
        {
            echo '<li class="lastRow">' . $books[$j]["name"] . "</li>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li>" . $books[$j]["name"] . "</li>";
        }        
    }
    // do whatever you need to break the row here
    $i = $j; 
}
```

In terms of actually displaying the `li` elements on a single row, you'll probably want to use `display:inline` or `inline-block` in your css.  `float:left` would work too... Try them all and see which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter for the rows and use a modulus to decide when to break the row in the display logic.